# Discrete math: Prove this number is an irrational number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Prove that the number
>
> $$\sqrt{5^0} + \sqrt{5^1} + \sqrt{5^2} $$
>
> is an irrational number. For this problem you cannot assume that any number is irrational to begin with. You cannot use prime factorization and your solution should include a lemma demonstrating that if $a^2$ is divisible by 5 then $a$ is divisible by 5.

I'm absolutely lost in regards to how to approach this problem, and I'm not sure what the textbook means by including a lemma demonstrating that if $a^2$ is divisible by 5 then $a$ is divisible by 5. Any hints or help would be appreciated.

All these solutions were super helpful, thank you so much!!

Comment: It would help if you used [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Do you know what $\sqrt{5^0}$ and $\sqrt{5^2}$ are?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. I know that sqrt(5^0) is 1, and sqrt(5^2) is 5, but I'm not given anything else in the textbook.

Comment: Do you know that the sum of a rational number and an irrational number is an irrational number?

Comment: I actually didn't know that. I'll take that into consideration, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question can be written as
$${\sqrt{5^0} + \sqrt{5^1} + \sqrt{5^2}},$$
which is equal to
$${6 + \sqrt{5}}.$$
Now, the question simplifies to proving that $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational (as 6 is rational, and rational + irrational = irrational).
Now you go about doing it the normal way of proving $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational where $p$ is any prime:
Assume that $\sqrt{5}$ is rational and equal to $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $b$ is not equal to $0$.
This gives you
$${\sqrt{5} = \frac{a}{b}}$$
$${\implies 5 = \frac{a^2}{b^2}}$$
$${\implies 5\cdot b^2 = a^2}$$
Now $a^2$ is a multiple of $5$, and since if $a^2$ is a multiple of $5$, $a$ has to be a multiple of $5$, we can write $a = 5k$:
$${5\cdot b^2 = (5k)^2}$$
$${\implies b^2 = 5\cdot k^2}$$
Applying the same logic to $b$, we get that even $b$ is a multiple of $5$! This is a contradiction as we assumed $a$ and $b$ were co-prime!
Hence, $\sqrt{5}$ has to be irrational!

This all relies on the fact that if $a^2$ is a multiple of $5$, then $a$ has to be a multiple of $5$

We prove the contrapositive:  If $a$ is not a multiple of $5$, then $a^2$ is not a multiple of $5$ either.

Let $a \equiv k$ (mod $5$), where $k$ is not $0$ ($5$ does not divide $a$).
Therefore, $a = 5n + k$, where n is an integer.
Therefore, $a^2 = 25n^2 + 10k + k^2 = 5(5n^2 + 2k) + k^2$.
We can see that this will only be a multiple of $5$ if $k^2$ is a multiple of $5$.
By putting in all possible values of $k$ $(1,2,3,4)$, you can show that it is not a multiple of $5$.
Hence, the assumption that if $a^2$ is a multiple of $5$, then $a$ is a multiple of $5,$ holds true.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Are any of the three numbers rational anyway? Remember that rational + irrational = irrational.

You need to demonstrate that $$q^2=5\lambda \implies q=5\mu$$ for some $\lambda,\mu$

Demonstrate this by proving the opposite is true (I.e. That if $q$ is not a multiple of $5$; $q^2$ won't be either). Suppose we have $q=5\mu+D$, where $D$ is not a multiple of $5$. Evaluating $q^2$, can you see that will never be a multiple of $5$? That is an example of proof by contrapositive, and will suffice as the lemma you seek.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You'd help yourself out a lot by evaluating $\sqrt{5^0}$ and $\sqrt{5^2}$. You might as well want to prove that $\sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{R - Q}$ because you're not supposed to take that as a fact as per the question, this would include the use of the lemma demonstrating that if $5 \mid a^2 \implies 5 \mid a$. Now assume that $\sqrt{5^0}+\sqrt{5^1}+\sqrt{5^2}$ is rational and prove by contradiction that the number indeed is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of a rational number and an irrational number is an irrational number (otherwise the difference of two rational numbers would be irrational, but that can't be) and $\sqrt{5^0}+\sqrt{5^2} = 6$ is rational, so the problem boils down to showing that $\sqrt 5$ is irrational.  To prove that, assume the contrary, i.e., $\sqrt 5 =a/b,$ where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime integers (if they weren't relatively prime, then the fraction could be reduced).  Therefore $5b^2=a^2,$ so $5$ divides $a^2=a \times a$, but since $5$ is prime, this means $5$ divides $a,$ but then $5$ divides $b$, so our assumption that $\sqrt 5=a/b$ with $a$ and $b$ relatively prime integers has led to a contradiction and $\sqrt 5$ is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $A=\sqrt{5^0} + \sqrt{5^1} + \sqrt{5^2}$ is  rational number.

We have: $$A=6+\sqrt{5}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow A-6=\sqrt{5}$$

It is easy to see $LHS$ is rational number and $RHS$ is irrational number.

**Prove**: $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational number.

Assume $\sqrt{5}$ is rational number, then we can let $$\sqrt 5=\frac{a}{b}(a;b\in Z;b\ne 0)$$ where $(a;b)=1 (1)$

Or $$5=\frac{a^2}{b^2}\Leftrightarrow a^2=5b^2\Leftrightarrow a\vdots5 \text{(5 is prime number)}$$

$$\Rightarrow a^2\vdots 25\Rightarrow 5b^2\vdots 25 \Rightarrow b \vdots 5\Rightarrow (a;b)\ne 1 (2)$$

$(1);(2)$ we have $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational number.